# Best approach for in memory manipulation of text file in memory: read as byte[] first? read as File.ReadAllText() then save as binary?

Tags: c#, windows, io, arrays

I need to change a file in memory, and currently I read the file to memory into a byte[] using a filestream and a binaryreader.

I was wondering whats the best approach to change that file in memory, convert the byte[] to string, make changes and do an Encoding.GetBytes()?   or Read the file first as string using File.ReadAllText() and then Encoding.GetBytes()? or any approach will work without caveats?

Any special approaches? I need to replace specific text inside files with additional chars or replacement strings, several 100,000 of files. Reliability is preferred over efficiency. Files are text like HTML, not binary files.

Comment: What size are the files?

Comment: Small files, 10 to 100 kb generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the files using `File.ReadAllText()`, modify them, then do `byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(your_modified_string_from_file)`. Use the encoding with which the files were saved. This will give you an array of `byte[]`. You can convert the `byte[]` to a stream like this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
```

**Edit:**
It looks like one of the `Add` methods in the API can take a byte array, so you don't have to use a stream.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the source file encoding, so that when saving it back I use the same one?

Comment: I don't know of a way to detect the encoding for text files. I don't know if the encoding matters in this case, because you are giving the file to SharePoint already converted to bytes.

Comment: Thank you, code finished, scaled with testing of 10,000 files, detected the files for explicit encoding for two scenarios, works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely making things harder on yourself by reading into bytes first. Just use a StreamReader. You can probably get away with using ReadLine() and processing a line at a time. This can seriously reduce your app's memory usage, especially if you're working with that many files.

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(originalFile))
using (var writer = File.CreateText(tempFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        var temp = DoMyStuff(line);
        writer.WriteLine(temp);
    }
}

File.Delete(originalFile);
File.Move(tempFile, originalFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the size of the files, I would use `File.ReadAllText` to read them and `File.WriteAllText` to wirte them. This frees you up from the responsibility of having to call `Close` or `Dispose` on either read or write.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't want to read a *text* file on a binary level - just use `File.ReadAllText()` and supply it with the correct encoding used in the file (there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) for that). If the file encoding is UTF8 or UTF32 *usually* the method can automatically detect and use the correct endcoding. Same applies to writing it back - if it's not UTF8 specify which encoding you want.

Comment: So when writing back the file wont be to the file system, will call an API to save it to SharePoint 2010, using a stream or byte[] are required by the API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection_members.aspx in the Add methods, so I need at the end to convert it to such a stream. So after making the changes to the file should Encoding.GetBytes work?